# How to select IDs of inputs created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

### What i'm trying to do :

#### The working concept in JS :

In a basic form, i'm trying to reproduce **[this](https://jsbin.com/qilapab/edit?html,js,output)** in a C# app

To clarify, user has to be able to choose how many parts there is (and name each part).

=> *Example : My item has two parts, part_1 = "morning" and part_2 = "afternoon".*

---

In order to reproduce that, i've done the following :

#### form.aspx :

```csharp
<myform>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" type="number" ID="parts_counter" />
    <div id="content" runat="server"></div>
</myform>
```

*=> Why : The value of **parts_counter** is then meant to be read and with a javascript block (i know...) i create the inputs dynamically*

#### javascript_form.js :

```js
let counter = document.getElementById('parts_counter');
let content = document.getElementById('content');
counter.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  if (counter.value == 0) {
    content.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    content.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < counter.value; i++) {
      content.innerHTML += 
        "<input type='text' id='part_" + i + "' placeholder='Ex : Part name'/><br>";
        // ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // THIS IS THE PART I WANT TO BE ABLE TO READ IN C # Codebehind
    }
  }
})
```

#### form.aspx.designer.cs :

```csharp
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox part_0;
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox part_1;
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox part_2;
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox part_3;
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox part_4;
```

*=> Why : I tried to pre-register generated IDs, as there's no reason to have more than 5 parts in user scenario.*

#### form.aspx.cs :

```csharp
for (var i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(parts_counter.Text); i++)
{
    var nomPartie = "partie_" + i;
    var textBoxPartie = new TextBox();
    textBoxPartie.ID = nomPartie;
    // Do something for each
    i++;
}
```

*=> Why :*

1. I read value of the counter,
2. I loop for each value to do a server-side action

---

I (over) looked at some solutions on CodeProject, SO, ASPSnippets and i'm sure i've thought of this the wrong way, could you please tell me if there is a specific way to generate inputs and to get their IDs afterwards in codebehind ?

Every pennies are welcome

Comment: on change property. Create a new textbox. and add it to a container.

Comment: related: [Creating aspx textbox from codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016169/), If you need to change their Id you can bind a Onchange Event to them on creation

Comment: You cannot find them if you add textboxes with javascript. You need "real" dynamic controls. Or only read the Form Post collection of those textboxes.

Comment: So my error is to use the OnChange event in javascript where i would better use asp events. I'll test it out right away ! Thanks @DragandDrop

Comment: Thanks too @VDWWD for your contribution, i noted

Comment: To trigger the TextBox.TextChanged Event I think you may need the autoPostback property so it trigger the server call.